# Laravel, better way to link to images

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code which gets an image by id:

```
    //concertscontroller

    foreach($concerts as $concert){
        $concert->image = Image::find($concert->image_id);
    }
```

which grabs from this model

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * @property string path
 * @property string name
 * @property string alt
 * @property string caption
 * @property int width
 * @property int height
 */
class Image extends Model
{
    //
}
```

-

```
/**
 * @property string name
 * @property string address_1
 * @property string address_2
 * @property string address_3
 * @property float(10,6) coordinates
 * @property string copy
 * @property int imageId
 * @property string ticket_link
 * @property string info_link
 * @property DateTime datetime
 */

class Concerts extends Model
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
     */
    public function image()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Image','id','imageId');
        //I don't think this does anything
    }
}
```

I can't remember as I wrote it quite a while ago but I think the hasOne relationship should allow me to use some Laravel facade to get the image automatically. Does anyone know how to do this? If I'm doing it right tell me that too!

Comment: it not `return $this->hasOne('App\Image','id','imageId');` it should be: `return $this->hasOne('App\Image');`

Comment: This also depends on your database and that you have your foreign keys setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    foreach($concerts as $concert){
        $concert->image = Image::find($concert->image_id);
    }
```

-

```
 namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Image extends Model
    {
           public function concerts()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Concerts');
        }
    }
```

-

```
 class Concerts extends Model
    {
        /**
         * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
         */
        public function image()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App\Image','id','imageId');
            //I don't think this does anything
        }
    }
```

This should to the trick, after adding the belongsTo relationship.

Comment: Is this the case where one image can belong to several other classes?

Comment: This case iy woll belong to one class that you define in the function. You can say belongsToMany if you meed other relationship.